# SetEnv for a dynamic URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, setenv

what I am trying to do is to use SetEnv for a dynamic URL.
In example for index.php I do this

```
<IfModule somemodule.c>
<Files index.php>
    SetEnv somevariable
</Files>
</IfModule>
```

However If I wanted to do this for index.php?something=123 then what should I put in my .htaccess? Will it work with SetEnvIf request_URI somehow cause I couldn't get it to work. Another thing I think could be the solution is to use rewrite_mod but I have no idea how to do it. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mod_rewrite's `E` flag to set environment variables:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^something=123$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,E=somevariable]
```